# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm not sure how to debug this error.

I have a kendo grid that allows users to drag and drop to sort rows and also allows users to update a cell in those rows.  However after adding the sort functionality I get this error when trying to update a row:

```
 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined      TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
```

I have this code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DocumentProperties>(Model.CurrentList)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SortOrder).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.DisplayText).Title("Title");
            columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Title("File Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewDocument", new { id = "did" }, new { target = "_blank" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("did", "#: ID #")).Title("").Width(80); //creates link to view the uploaded document
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "DeleteDocument", new { id = "did" }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this document?');", style = "color:Red;" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("did", "#: ID #")).Title("").Width(80);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items.

            }).Title("").Width(80);
        })

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
              .Update(update => update.Action("DocAttributeUpdate", "Blurb"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item.
              .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
              .PageSize(20)
              .ServerOperation(false)

              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.ID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                  model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false); // Make the ID property not editable.
                  model.Field(p => p.SortOrder).Editable(false); // Make the SortOrder property not editable.
                  model.Field(p => p.FileName).Editable(false); // Make the FileName property not editable.
                  model.Field(p => p.DisplayText).Editable(true); // Make the DisplayText property editable.
              })

            )
         .Sortable(sortable => sortable
            .Enabled(true)
            )
         .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         //.Refresh(true) Need to figure this out.  Doesn't refresh properly. 
                .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(5))

            .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))               

        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row)) //make each row selectable

        )

        @(Html.Kendo().Sortable() //this adds the cool drag and drop sorting
                .For("#Grid")
                    .Filter("table > tbody > tr")
                    .Cursor("move")
                    .HintHandler("noHint")
                    .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
                    .ContainerSelector("#Grid tbody")
                    .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))

            )

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var noHint = $.noop;

        function placeholder(element) {
            return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
        }

        function onChange(e) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid"),
            skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
            oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
            newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
            dataItems = grid.dataSource.data(),
            dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid")); //grab your item and give it a new index. Then remove the item from the list and place in the new index.

            grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

            var dataList = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {

                dataList[i] = {
                    ID: dataItems[i].ID,
                    ClientId: dataItems[i].ClientId,
                    SortOrder: i,
                    DisplayText: dataItems[i].DisplayText,
                    Type: dataItems[i].Type,
                    MimeType: dataItems[i].MimeType,
                    FileName: dataItems[i].FileName

                };

            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Blurb/SaveSortOrder",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataList) //send our json string back to the server for sorting
                }

            })
        };
```

When I remove the code for:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
```

The update button works again, but I don't have my drag and drop sorting anymore.

jQuery Script:

```
<script>
                            jQuery(function() {
                                jQuery("#Grid").kendoGrid({
                                    "columns": [{
                                        "title": "Title",
                                        "headerAttributes": {
                                            "data-field": "DisplayText",
                                            "data-title": "Title"
                                        },
                                        "field": "DisplayText",
                                        "encoded": true,
                                        "editor": "\u003cinput class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"DisplayText\" name=\"DisplayText\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"field-validation-valid\" data-valmsg-for=\"DisplayText\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"
                                    }, {
                                        "title": "File Name",
                                        "headerAttributes": {
                                            "data-field": "FileName",
                                            "data-title": "File Name"
                                        },
                                        "field": "FileName",
                                        "encoded": true
                                    }, {
                                        "headerAttributes": {
                                            "data-field": "ID",
                                            "data-title": ""
                                        },
                                        "width": "80px",
                                        "template": "\u003ca href=\"/Blurb/ViewDocument/#: ID #\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eView\u003c/a\u003e",
                                        "field": "ID",
                                        "encoded": true
                                    }, {
                                        "headerAttributes": {
                                            "data-field": "ID",
                                            "data-title": ""
                                        },
                                        "width": "80px",
                                        "template": "\u003ca href=\"/Blurb/DeleteDocument/#: ID #\" onclick=\"return confirm(\u0027Are you sure you want to delete this document?\u0027);\" style=\"color:Red;\"\u003eRemove\u003c/a\u003e",
                                        "field": "ID",
                                        "encoded": true
                                    }, {
                                        "width": "80px",
                                        "command": [{
                                            "name": "edit",
                                            "buttonType": "ImageAndText",
                                            "text": "Edit"
                                        }]
                                    }],
                                    "pageable": {
                                        "pageSizes": [5, 10, 20],
                                        "buttonCount": 5
                                    },
                                    "sortable": true,
                                    "selectable": "Single, Cell",
                                    "resizable": true,
                                    "scrollable": false,
                                    "editable": {
                                        "confirmation": "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
                                        "confirmDelete": "Delete",
                                        "cancelDelete": "Cancel",
                                        "mode": "inline",
                                        "create": true,
                                        "update": true,
                                        "destroy": true
                                    },
                                    "messages": {
                                        "noRecords": "No records available."
                                    },
                                    "dataSource": {
                                        "type": (function() {
                                            if (kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']) {
                                                return 'aspnetmvc-ajax';
                                            } else {
                                                throw new Error('The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.');
                                            }
                                        })(),
                                        "transport": {
                                            "read": {
                                                "url": ""
                                            },
                                            "prefix": "",
                                            "update": {
                                                "url": "/Blurb/DocAttributeUpdate"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "pageSize": 20,
                                        "page": 1,
                                        "total": 3,
                                        "error": error_handler,
                                        "schema": {
                                            "data": "Data",
                                            "total": "Total",
                                            "errors": "Errors",
                                            "model": {
                                                "id": "ID",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "ID": {
                                                        "editable": false,
                                                        "type": "number"
                                                    },
                                                    "ClientId": {
                                                        "type": "number"
                                                    },
                                                    "SortOrder": {
                                                        "editable": false,
                                                        "type": "number",
                                                        "defaultValue": null
                                                    },
                                                    "DisplayText": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "Type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "MimeType": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "FileName": {
                                                        "editable": false,
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "Document": {
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "data": {
                                            "Data": [{
                                                "ID": 440,
                                                "ClientId": 16,
                                                "DisplayText": "Test Document",
                                                "FileName": "3182AscensionRecipientsDashboard (5).pdf",
                                                "Type": "Document",
                                                "MimeType": "application/pdf",
                                                "Document": {
                                                    "ID": 0,
                                                    "DocumentAttributeId": 0,
                                                    "FileContent": null ,
                                                    "Content": null
                                                },
                                                "SortOrder": 0
                                            }, {
                                                "ID": 5,
                                                "ClientId": 16,
                                                "DisplayText": "Summary Plan Description",
                                                "FileName": "Summary Plan Description.pdf",
                                                "Type": "Document",
                                                "MimeType": "application/pdf",
                                                "Document": {
                                                    "ID": 0,
                                                    "DocumentAttributeId": 0,
                                                    "FileContent": null ,
                                                    "Content": null
                                                },
                                                "SortOrder": 1
                                            }, {
                                                "ID": 6,
                                                "ClientId": 16,
                                                "DisplayText": "Summary Annual Report",
                                                "FileName": "SUMMARY ANNUAL REPORT.pdf",
                                                "Type": "Document",
                                                "MimeType": "application/pdf",
                                                "Document": {
                                                    "ID": 0,
                                                    "DocumentAttributeId": 0,
                                                    "FileContent": null ,
                                                    "Content": null
                                                },
                                                "SortOrder": 2
                                            }],
                                            "Total": 3,
                                            "AggregateResults": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the Jquery script that's rendered as a result of the kendo.mvc syntax.. you can view page source and get it

Comment: @Reddy I edited my post to include the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to approach edit a bit differently to get this work, although I might still try to figure out why my original way wasn't working. 
I had to add the toolbar feature of kendo and make the cell editable:

```
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Save();

    })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
```